# Sequence space norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am working on an assignment so I won't be stating the actual question, but it's about showing extensions of a linear functional in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and it says, I quote

> Determine all it's linear extensions to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the same norm if $\mathbb{R}^2$ is given
>
> 1. the $\ell^1 norm$
> 2. The $\ell^p$ norm

and I am primarely stuck on the wording here s I don't quite grasp what this norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ would be.

I know that the norm on $\ell^p$ is for $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)\in \ell^p$
$$||x||=(\sum_i x_i^p)^(1/p)$$
But this on $\mathbb{R}^2$ baffles me, would it be like viewing elements $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ as $(a,b,0,0,0,0,\ldots)\in\ell^p$? Then it makes some sense to me, or am I completely out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $l_p$ norm for $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is this:

$$||(x,y)||_p=(|x|^p+|y|^p)^{1/p}$$

So basically your intuition of putting zeros after the second place in an infinite dimensional vector is correct, but in fact there is no need to carry them around.

Comment: So it is as I said viewing it as $(x,y,0,0,0,\ldots)$ then?

Comment: Yes, it is, but then it is easier to think of them as two dimensional.

Comment: I agree on that which is what it reduces to, but it made no sense without that middle step of translation. Thank you.